# Pycharm doesn't detect installed pymongo package

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pymongo, egg

**UPDATE:** pycharm can now locate the package, but I can not seem to import anything from the package itself.

-----ORIGINAL----
I've tried installing pymongo through pip. When I check settings, it clearly displays that the package is installed in my venv interpreter.

The location of the installed package is as follows: "C:\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.7.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg"

Is it something to do with the .egg file?

(I've already tried easy_install but to no avail)

[image]

Comment: If the package clearly displays in the settings for your interpreter, how exactly does the issue "Pycharm doesn't detect installed pymongo package" present itself? What's the actual error and where does it occur?

Comment: I'm not able to import anything from the package itself. Please check included image if it helps.

Comment: Have you actually tried running it from PyCharm? I have noticed that PyCharm sometimes falsely shows unresolved imports. Also, restarting PyCharm after installing a package using external methods (e.g. pip) might help, if you have not yet done already

Comment: I tried restarting pyCharm but the problem persists. But I've also noticed that PyCharm sometimes shows false unresolved imports. I'll try ignoring and see if it works.

Comment: problem is simple: you should avoid naming your module after some another existing module, your file is called **pymongo.py**, rename it to something different like **playing_with_pymongo.py**

Comment: Yes! that worked! Wow, the issue really seems silly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved.

As pointed out by **Azat Ibrakov**, the module name was the same as package name that was causing the problem.

> problem is simple: you should avoid naming your module after some another existing module, your file is called pymongo.py, rename it to something different like playing_with_pymongo.py

Answer (score 0):

press below keys in pycharm -

> ctrl + alt + s

a dialog box will get open.
Then go to-

> project->project interpreter

once you are there, let the packages load. then click on apply and Ok.

If you want to check whether the problem is in pycharm of python, go to command prompt and type python, import pymongo and press enter. If things workout well, it means the problem is in pycharm, but if they don't then it means the problem is in installing pymongo.